# Kendo foreignkey column change event

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with foreign key columns. how do i get an event when the user changes the value from the foreign key dropdown?
I've tried specifying an id and change event but itdoesnt seem to work.

```
columns.ForeignKey(c => c.Colour, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["colours"], "Id", "Desc")
.Width(300).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "colChanged", data_value_primitive = "true" });


    $('#colChanged').on("change", function () {
         var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     //NOT GETTING HERE
        console.log("Selected value..: " + selectedValue);
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `~Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder for a `GridForeignKey.cshtml` file. It contains the definition of the DropDownList editor used for the foreign key column. You can specify the JavaScript function that will be executed when a change event fires for the DropDownList:

```
@model object
       
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .Events(ev=>ev.Change("onFkDdlChange"))        
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Whenever you have a Grid with a ForeignKey column add a `onFkDdlChange` function to that View and it will be executed.

Comment: There are foreignkey columns in other pages too, If I do this then I've to make changes to all those pages to implement onFkDdlChange

Comment: That's correct. An option for the specific Grid can be to use the [ForeignKey configuration overload](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridcolumnfactory#foreignkeysystemlinqexpressionsexpressionsystemactionsystemstringsystemstringsystemboolean) that allows you to specify that a server editor should be used and provide the name of the editor via the [EditorTemplateName](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridboundcolumnbuilder#editortemplatenamesystemstring) configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating an editor called ColourComboEditor specific to this column:

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m).HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
     .DataTextField("colours")
     .DataValueField("Id")
     .Events(e => e.Change("ComboValChanged"))
     .DataSource(s => s.Read(r => r.Action("GetColours", "ColourSelection")).ServerFiltering(false))
     .AutoBind(true)
)
```

Annotation:

```
[UIHint("ColourComboEditor")]
public string Colour { get; set; }
```

column is not a foreignkey anymore:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Colour).Width(300);
```